# What's the logic within LINREG function in pine (trading view)?

Tags: c#, charts, pine-script

So i'm building some sort of charts in C#, i'm basically reverse-engineering what I need from TradingView functions which uses PineScript.

I'm Kind of stuck with this one "LINREG" because there is no deep explanation on what's being calculated whitin the function:
https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v1/#fun_linreg

**interface**: linreg(source, length, offset) → series

**formula**: linreg = intercept + slope * (length - 1 - offset)

- where length: is the y argument
- offset is the z argument
- "*intercept and slope are the values calculated with the least squares method on source series (x argument)*" **<-- This third bullet is a total mistery**

Does somebody has the logic behind this 3rd bullet?, not necessary in C# code, to understand the logic will be enought for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

LINREG short for linear regression, a statistical tool you may know about already.

This website will help you with understanding the formula-

https://budgeting.thenest.com/calculate-linear-regression-lines-slopes-stock-prices-33550.html

Comment: Will check that one, I already gave a try to several other sites, that explained it very poorly or leaving several gaps in the logic. Need something more "mathematically explained" if you will.

Comment: I use it heavily while trading but unfortunately I am not a mathematician. I will point you to the best script I know and use on linear regression assuming you're a pine script expert. You might figure it out with the code.
https://in.tradingview.com/script/efXI515C-Linear-Regression-Channel/

Also, look at this video. Much easier to visualize than reading about it.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m88h75F3Rl8

Comment: Hm, yes pine code helps a lot, i'ts kinda easy to translate to C#, besides I can test it inside tradingView first, to confirm it gives me the same result than "linreg". I will certainly give it a try on that one. Thanks.

Comment: @Yogurtu - did you ever understand this/port to c#?

Answer (score -2):

`x` argument is the `source` series.

There is modern reference man:
[https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta{dot}linreg](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dlinreg)

Comment: Not asking what is X. And the link you gave pretty much explains the same than v1.